# ActiveRecord after_rollback callback not triggered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

Since upgrading to Rails 6, I'm unable to get the after_rollback callback to fire. I've verified this doesn't work on Rails `6.0.3.6` or `6.1.3.1`. Any help is appreciated!

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_rollback do |user|
    puts "You have rolled back!"
  end

  validates_presence_of :name
end


> User.first.update!(name: nil)
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Name cant be blank)

> User.create!
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Name cant be blank)
```

According to the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_rollback) the `after_rollback` should be triggered after *a create, update, or destroy are rolled back*

Comment: Please paste your rails log to see if there is really a `ROLLBACK`.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/36965 this seems to be a known issue

Comment: @max yeah and when it bails, it should trigger a rollback. So when you create/update/delete it should *always* call after_commit or after_rollback.

Answer (score 0):

The default DB transactions are only opened after successful validation of the entity to be saved unless you manually open them.
Try

```
User.transaction do
  User.first.update!(name: nil)
end
```